# QuickSort descending order

Tags: java, quicksort

I am trying to implement QuickSort in a descending order. I have tried to trace through my code to see why it is only partially-sorted. My input was an int array of: {3,4,6,1,9,7}. After sorting, I got {9,4,7,6,3,1}, where 4 is not in the correct place.

```
    public int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
    {
       int pivot = arr[right];
       int i = left - 1;
       for(int j = right; j >= left; j--)
    {
        if (arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            i = i + 1;                                      
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]= arr[j];
            arr[j]= temp;
        }
    }

    int temp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = temp;

    return i + 1;

    }

public void sorting(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int q = partition(arr, left, right);
        sorting(arr, left, q - 1);
        sorting(arr, q + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see examples of quicksort implementation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) it includes explanation of logic and code samples.

Comment: For problems like this it is really useful to get a pen and paper and explicitly write down what your algorithm is doing, you will eventually see what is going on.

Comment: This is a partition method.  It's not a sort method.  Where's the sort method?

Comment: @LouisWasserman kindly view updated post, I have traced through my code yet still not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
public int partition(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int i = left;
    for(int j = left + 1; j <= right; j++){
        if (arr[j] > pivot){
            i = i + 1;
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]= arr[j];
            arr[j]= temp;
        }
    }

    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[left];
    arr[left] = temp;

    return i;

}

public void sorting(int arr[], int left, int right){
    if(left < right)
    {
        int q = partition(arr, left, right);
        sorting(arr, left, q);
        sorting(arr, q + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this making the pivot the left-most element in the array then? Is it possible to make the right-most element the pivot and still have it in descending order?

Comment: Are you required to do that? As I saw in your attempt, just because you should sort it in descending order, doesn't mean you should invert every single operation (what is left turns into right, for starting from right instead of left...)

Comment: No, but I was wondering why it would be easier to do it by the left-most element instead of the right, because most quicksort algorithms I have seen use the last element in the array.

Comment: Quite the opposite in fact, Hoare's partition (the creator of Quicksort) gets the first element as pivot and this approach is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is right but need a few modifications
Check out following code to correct your result.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] ar, int start, int end) {
    if (start <end) {
        int p = partition(ar, start, end);
        quickSort(ar, start, p-1);
        quickSort(ar, p+1, end);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] ar, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = ar[end];
    int i = start;
    for (int j = end; j>= start; j--) {
        if (ar[j] > pivot) {
            int temp1 = ar[i];
            ar[i] = ar[j];
            ar[j] = temp1;
            
            i = i+1;
        }
    }
    int temp2 = ar[i];
    ar[i] = ar[end];
    ar[end] = temp2;
    return i;
}
```